# norms on a field and induced metric

Tags: metric-spaces, local-field

Let $F$ be a field. A **norm** on $F$ is a map $|\,|:F\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with conditions:

- $|x|\ge 0$ and $|x|=0$ if and only if $x=0$.
- $|xy|=|x|.|y|$
- $|x+y|\le |x|+|y|$

A norm $|\,|$ is said to be  **non-archimedean** if

- $|x+y|\le \max \{ |x|,|y|\}$ for all $x,y\in F$.

Observations:

(1) Let $|\, |$ be a norm on $F$. This defines a metric on $F$ by $d(x,y)=|x-y|$.

(2) If $|\,|$ is non-archimedean then the metric $d$ is bounded: there is $M\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $|x|\le M$ for all $x\in F$ or equivalently $d(x,y)\le M$ for all $x,y\in F$.

**Q.1** Are there some *bounded metrics* on $F$ which is not induced by a non-archimedean norm on $F$?

**Q.2** Are there metrics on $F$ which are not induced by a norm on $F$?

For **Q.2** I was thinking to take usual metric on $\mathbb{R}$, and compose with a homeomprphism $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $x\mapsto 2x$ to get a new metric on $\mathbb{R}$; this is not induced by any norm on $\mathbb{R}$ since for norm, $|1|=1$.

**Q.1** I am not getting some obvious answers as in **Q.2**.

Comment: I missed that, sorry. Yes, then the norm of $1_F$ should be $1$.

Comment: Its Ok sir. Thanks!

Comment: Observation (2) is false! If $||$ is non-archimedean, then $|n1_F|\leq1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ but it is possible that $\{|x|:x\in F\}$ is dense in $[0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A positive answer to Q.2 is obviously also a positive answer to Q.1, so you probably want to rephrase Q.1 as "Are there some bounded metrics on $F$ which are induced by norm, but are not induced by a non-archimedean norm"?

As for question 2, consider the metric 
$$d((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))=(|x_1-x_2|^p+|y_1-y_2|^p)^{1/p}$$
defined on the complex field $\mathbb{C}$, where a complex number is represented by $x+iy$. If $0<p<1$, the unit ball of this metric (around zero, say) is not convex. It is easy to check that the unit ball of a norm must be convex, hence this class of metrics are not induced by a norm.

Answer (score 2):

For any metric space, there is a bounded metric inducing the same topology on it.
For example, one can replace a metric $d$ by $d'(x,y)=\min(d(x,y),1)$. So on $\Bbb  R$ one has the bounded metric $\min(|x-y|,1)$. This induces the standard topology,
not the totally disconnected topology induced by a non-Archimedean topology.

Comment: The first point I was missing (also $d'(x,y)=d(x,y)/[1+d(x,y)]$ defines same topology as $d$, am I right?] and $d'$ is bounded metric.

Comment: Yes, that's another way of creating an bounded metric inducing the same topology. @Beginner